# Prove that numbers represented by principal form are the subgroup of squares

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The book "Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$" has the following exercise:
[image]

I have a doubt at item (b), tried to skip to item (c) and couldn't figure it too.

For context, $\chi$ is the map $[m] \mapsto \left( \frac{D}{m} \right)$, this being a Jacobi symbol.

Item (a) follows easily from applying mod $8$ over the identity $4af(x,y) = (2ax +y)^2 - D y^2$.

Item (b) follows a previous result if $m$ is odd. If $m$ is even we can rewrite $m$ as $2^k \cdot d$, $d$ odd and calculate the Jacobi symbol:
$$\left( \frac{D}{2^k\cdot d} \right)  = \left( \frac{D}{d} \right)\left( \frac{D}{2} \right)^k$$
Then $\left( \frac{D}{2} \right) = 1$ because $D \equiv 1$ mod $8$ and the above expression equals 1 iff $D$ is a square mod $d$.

The question is, how do i prove that $\left( \frac{D}{d} \right) = 1$? There is a theorem that says that for $d$ odd then  $\left( \frac{D}{d} \right) = 1$ if and only if $d$ is represented by a form of discriminant $D$. I know $m$ is represented by such a form, but i don't know how to prove the same for $d$.

At item (c) i could use the hint to prove that every value represented by the form is a square, but i have no idea how to prove the converse.